# how to get reference id of contact when account is update contact should be also update

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

```
 if (entity.LogicalName == "account")
            {
                Entity Account = (Entity)service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true));
                tracingService.Trace("1");
                Guid ContactGuid = Account.Id;
                tracingService.Trace("9");
                //throw new Exception("Contact guid" + ContactGuid);
                Entity objContact = (Entity)service.Retrieve("contact", ((EntityReference)Account.Attributes["new_account"]).Id, new ColumnSet(true));
                tracingService.Trace("2");
                string Updatename = Account.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
                tracingService.Trace("3");
                objContact.Attributes["fullname"] = Updatename;
                tracingService.Trace("4");
                string Updateemail = Account.GetAttributeValue<string>("emailaddress1");
                tracingService.Trace("5");
                objContact.Attributes["emailaddress1"] = Updateemail;
                tracingService.Trace("6");
                string Updateaddress = Account.GetAttributeValue<string>("address1_composite");
                tracingService.Trace("7");
                objContact.Attributes["address1_composite"] = Updateaddress;

                service.Update(objContact);
            }
```

Comment: Please desribe your problem in more detail. In the current state it is absolutely unclear what you mean.

Comment: I am trying to get created record of contact when account is update and contact should be updated....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the ID of the Primary Contact of the Account:

```
EntityReference primaryContact = Account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("primarycontactid");
Guid contactGuid = primaryContact.Id;
```

Note that the relationship `contact_customer_accounts` for all Contacts of the Account is 1:N, so you would need to retrieve them from the relationship and loop over them.